# How to insert custom option into Magento theme product view template?

Tags: magento, view, themes

I've created a custom Magento theme for a jewelry store and for a ring that I've
added as a sample product, I created a custom option for ring size (a SELECT field).

How do I insert *just* that custom option  above the 'add to cart' button in my
product view.phtml template file?

Here is the page: http://s1.mynewsitereview.com/fire-opal-ring.html

And here is my view.phtml code:

```
<?php $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output'); ?>
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
</script>
<div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?></div>

<div class="product-view">
    <div class="product-essential">
    <form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
        <div class="no-display">
            <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="" />
        </div>
        
        <div class="product-img-box">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('media') ?>
        </div>      

        <div class="product-shop">
            <h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
            
            <?php if ($_product->getShortDescription()):?>
                    <p><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description') ?></p>
            <?php endif;?>      
            
            <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?> 

            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('alert_urls') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extrahint') ?>

            <p class="email-friend">
            <?php if ($this->canEmailToFriend()): ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/product')->getEmailToFriendUrl($_product) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Email to a Friend') ?></a><br>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, false, true)?>
            </p>

                <div class="add-to-box">
                    <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
                        <div><?php if( $this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow() || $_compareUrl=$this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddUrl($_product)): ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>             
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
                </div>

        </div>

    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
        productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
            if (this.validator.validate()) {
                var form = this.form;
                var oldUrl = form.action;

                if (url) {
                   form.action = url;
                }
                var e = null;
                try {
                    this.form.submit();
                } catch (e) {
                }
                this.form.action = oldUrl;
                if (e) {
                    throw e;
                }

                if (button && button != 'undefined') {
                    button.disabled = true;
                }
            }
        }.bind(productAddToCartForm);

        productAddToCartForm.submitLight = function(button, url){
            if(this.validator) {
                var nv = Validation.methods;
                delete Validation.methods['required-entry'];
                delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required'];
                delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required-by-name'];
                // Remove custom datetime validators
                for (var methodName in Validation.methods) {
                    if (methodName.match(/^validate-datetime-.*/i)) {
                        delete Validation.methods[methodName];
                    }
                }

                if (this.validator.validate()) {
                    if (url) {
                        this.form.action = url;
                    }
                    this.form.submit();
                }
                Object.extend(Validation.methods, nv);
            }
        }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
    //]]>
    </script>
    </div>

    <div class="product-collateral">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('other');?>
            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) ?>
            <?php endif;?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm looking for the block of code to add to display the custom options form in a .phtml, have found any solution ? If so please show me how you did it. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this code

`<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true) ?>
        <?php endif;?>`

in your view.phtml file just above the

`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>`

Comment: I came to the same conclusion about an hour and a half ago. Adding this code and tweaking it a smidge gave me exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for answering though! I appreciate it.